# Remote EJB testing with JUnit and glassfish 4

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, glassfish, ejb-3.1

I am working on automated testing of EJB3 beans. I have managed to create a sample application, with the following code:

(The test enviroment is based on 4 modules: EJB client, EJB, EAR - containing the ejb client & ejb - and the junit tester project).

Interface:

```
package remote.test;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface TestBeanRemote {
public void method1();  
public int method2();   
}
```

EJB:

```
package remote.test
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Remote
@Stateless
public class Testbean implements TestBeanRemote {
public Testbean() {
}
@Override
public void method1() {
}
@Override
public int method2() {
return 42;
}
}
```

For helping Junit testing, I use the Glassfish4 ORB/IIOP port with default settings.

I have a utility class for setting this up:

```
import java.util.Properties;
public class Util {
public static Properties getInitProperties() {
Properties result = new Properties();
result.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                   "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
result.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
result.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
                "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
result.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
result.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
return result;
}
}
```

And here is the testing code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import remote.test;
public class JunitTester {
private TestBeanRemote testBean;
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(Util.getInitProperties());
testBean = (TestBeanRemote ) context.lookup("java:global/.../Testbean!...TestBeanRemote");
}
@Test
public void methodTest(){
    long n = testBean.method2();
    assertEquals(42, n);
}
}
```

('...' above means the shortening of the full package)

And at this point everything works. Which should sound good, so I want to implement this in a specific application, where I get into problems.

So, I have an existing application, where I have the following modules:
EAR:
JPA module
EJB client module
EJB impl. module
WAR module

Plus, I have created a simple java application project, where I would like to implement the same testing, as above. 
So I have added the same utility class as above, and added the same junit testing code, where I have changed the

```
 private TestBeanRemote testBean;
```

to an existing Remote interfaced bean of my application, and changed the jndi name to the corresponding name (the jdni names are all given by glassfish).

And this doesn't work, I get a NullPointerException at the .lookup() method:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:347)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:384)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:329)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:477)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
```

And I can't find why. The two applications are running in the same glassfish server. I have tried to compare the codes, but only difference is that my existing remote bean has EntityManager persistencecontext.

Anyone has any idea on where should I look for problems? What could cause this error?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you consider using [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) for testing? It would give you the ability to run your test within a real container without caring for the details.

Comment: Yes, but for our purposes Arquillian wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the differences. For some reason, both projects were referencing the gf-client-module.jar from glassfish 3.1 (the two glassfish installations are near each other).

The bigger project didn't run, because it was referencing newer apis (like JPA2 or JSF 2.2), so I got the given error.